# Get rid of arrows when not needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

How do I get rid of the arrows when I don't need them? Currently, I have four slides, so for most desktop screens, I won't need the arrows. The script that I'm using isn't working.

I've only included the code I added to remove the arrows whenever fewer than 4 slides are showing at once.

Any ideas?

```
    <script>
     //dont show navigation arrows on one slide if not using looped slides
        var swiper__slidecount = mySwiper.slides.length;
        if (swiper__slidecount < 4) {
          $('.swiper-button-prev,.swiper-button-next').remove();
        }
  </script>
```

Comment: What arrows, what slides, what on earth are you talking about?

Comment: What “isn’t working”? How? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. When is that code supposed to be run? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're missing the jQuery CDN. ADD:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> 
</script>
```

to your code. Also, .remove() requires an index value.

An alternative solution would be:

```
  <script>
     //dont show navigation arrows on one slide if not using looped slides
        var swiper__slidecount = mySwiper.slides.length;
        if (swiper__slidecount < 4) {
          $('.swiper-button-prev,.swiper-button-next').outerHTML="";
        }
  </script>
```